# attach to remote docker container in visual studio code with user other than root

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with the Docker extension. I'm connecting to docker on a remote machine through SSH.
When I click on a container in the docker extension and do "Attach Visual Studio Code" if the container was started with the root user then it attaches fine. If it was started with a different uid/gid then I get the following. Not that the image has the user and groups setup correctly from the dockerfile.

```
[4909 ms] 
[4910 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[4947 ms] User 33333:45678 not found in /etc/passwd.
[4948 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server
[4982 ms] 
[4982 ms] 
[4982 ms] Exit code 1
[4982 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-remote
[5019 ms] 
[5019 ms] 
[5019 ms] Exit code 1
[5019 ms] Start: Run in container: set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[5057 ms] 
[5057 ms] mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
[5058 ms] Exit code 1
[5059 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/d5e9aa0227e057a60c82568bf31c04730dc15dcd
[5095 ms] 
[5096 ms] 
[5096 ms] Exit code 1
[5096 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit d5e9aa0227e057a60c82568bf31c04730dc15dcd
[5096 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /root/.vscode-server/bin/d5e9aa0227e057a60c82568bf31c04730dc15dcd_1595365126276
[5133 ms] 
[5134 ms] mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
[5134 ms] Exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am currently stuck with the exact same issue.

Comment: @mathamateur sorry for the late reply - I solved it only in the way described below. It worked since then fairly well, so I didn't feel an urgent need to create a better solution afterwards... However if you hear of one, please do share!

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem in a fairly brute-force way. I added a specific user directly in the Dockerfile (first defining the group they belong to):

```
RUN groupadd --gid $GID $GROUPNAME
RUN useradd --uid $UID --gid $GID -m $USERNAME
```

and then in the `docker-compose` added the following line under all services I wanted to log in to with that specific UID/GID:

```
user: $USERNAME
```

For `docker-compose` you will need first to export the username explicitely before building your containers:

```
export USERNAME="Max Mustermann"
```

(unless, of course, you're using your own local username, in which case just writing `user: $USER` without exporting anything is enough.

The reason for adding the user in the Dockerfile is that you want to have user data listed in `/etc/passwd` so that VSCode can pick them up. If you don't have access to Dockerfile you can also make a small shell script that is going to attach to the container as the default (root) user and add the desired UID/GID subsequently.

After this VSCode automatically attached to the container as that specific user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the machine running the Docker environment, you can connect to the remote machine through the `Remote Explorer` extension. Install `Docker` extension inside the machine. Then, use the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) for this from `Docker`. This is the gist:

Create the `docker` group:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Add your `user` to the `docker` group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated. If you’re running Linux in a virtual machine, it `restart` the virtual machine for changes to take effect.

**Warning**

The `docker` group grants `root-level` privileges to the user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).